# How to change tab delimited in to comma delimited in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know if this is something possible. I am trying to append 12 files into a single file. One of the files is tab delimited and the rest comma delimitted. I loaded all the 12 files into dataframe and append it into an empty dataframe one by one in a loop.

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in list_of_files:
    file = pd.read_csv(filename)
    dfFilename = pd.DataFrame(file)
    df = df.append(dfFilename, ignore_index=True)
```

But the big file is not in the format I wanted it to be. And I think the problem is with the tab delimited file. And I tried to run the code without the tab delimited file and the format of the appended file is fine. So I was thinking if it is possible to change the tab delimited format into comma delimited using pandas.

Thank you for your help and suggestion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to tell Pandas that the file is tab delimited when you import it. You can pass a delimiter to the read_csv method but in your case, since the delimiter changes by file, you want to pass None - this will make Pandas auto-detect the correct delimiter.

Change your read_csv line to:

```
pd.read_csv(filename,sep=None)
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks dear

Answer (score 3):

For the file that is tab-separated, you should use:

```
file = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t")
```

Pandas `read_csv` has quite a lot of parameters, check it out in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)