# Removing inconsistent spaces in columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I've to read a file which has inconsistent spaces as column delimiters. Any suggestions how I can read this using Python. Eventually I need this data to be in a pyspark dataframe.

File content is as follows:

```
AutoID               AutoGUID                             ServerID         ReceivedUTC
244021856            B22AD225-1373-4F13-9ADE-38963BA67835 GOEQXPWEPO020    2019-11-02 13:57:25.973
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026698/how-to-make-separator-in-pandas-read-csv-more-flexible-wrt-whitespace-for-irreg does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this link [How to change tab delimited in to comma delimited in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524199/how-to-change-tab-delimited-in-to-comma-delimited-in-pandas) 
You can change the delimiters to None or to a specific character in pandas
like:

```
pd.read_csv(filename,sep=None)
```

or

```
file = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t")
```

Feel free to check the documentation as it might give you some hints https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

This file format is known as a fixed-width file. `pandas` has a function specifically for reading this type of file: [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

By default, `pandas` will infer the width of each column. If you find that it has trouble doing so, you can investigate the `colspecs` optional parameter.

You can convert the resulting `pandas.DataFrame` to a pyspark DataFrame using:

```
spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

as [documented by pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame).

Answer (score 0):

In **`Python`** we can use regular expression **`split`**, we are splitting data based on inconsistent spaces.

```
import re
re.split("\\s+",'a b   c')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

**`In Pyspark:`**

```
#sample data
$ cat i.txt
one two   three   four   five
six    seven    eight nine ten
```

---

```
cols=["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]
spark.sparkContext.textFile("<file_path>/i.txt").map(lambda x:re.split("\\s+",x)).toDF(cols).show()

#creating dataframe on the file with inconsistent spaces.
#+----+-----+-----+----+----+
#|col1| col2| col3|col4|col5|
#+----+-----+-----+----+----+
#| one|  two|three|four|five|
#| six|seven|eight|nine| ten|
#+----+-----+-----+----+----+
```